# Copy between two streams in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, copy

I have been using the following code to Compress data in .Net 4.0:

```
public static byte[] CompressData(byte[] data_toCompress)
{

    using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream inFile = new MemoryStream(data_toCompress))
        using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            inFile.CopyTo(Compress);

        }
        return outFile.ToArray();
    }

}
```

However, in .Net 2.0 Stream.CopyTo method is not available. So, I tried making a replacement:

```
public static byte[] CompressData(byte[] data_toCompress)
{

    using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream inFile = new MemoryStream(data_toCompress))
        using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            //inFile.CopyTo(Compress);
            Compress.Write(inFile.GetBuffer(), (int)inFile.Position, (int)(inFile.Length - inFile.Position));
        }
        return outFile.ToArray();
    }

}
```

The compression fails, though, when using the above attempt - I get an error saying:

> MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed.

Could anyone offer any help on this issue? I'm really not sure what else to do here.

Thank you,
Evan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have access to the array already, why don't you do this:

```
using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        Compress.Write(data_toCompress, 0, data_toCompress.Length);
    }
    return outFile.ToArray();
}
```

Most likely in the sample code you are using `inFile.GetBuffer()` will throw an exception since you do not use the [right constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y0t45kk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) - not all `MemoryStream` instances allow you access to the internal buffer - you have to look for this in the documentation:

> Initializes a new instance of the MemoryStream class based on the
>   specified region of a byte array, with the CanWrite property set as
>   specified, **and the ability to call GetBuffer set as specified**.

This should work - but is not needed anyway in the suggested solution:

```
using (MemoryStream inFile = new MemoryStream(data_toCompress, 
                                              0, 
                                              data_toCompress.Length, 
                                              false, 
                                              true))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Back to the basics for me I guess -

Answer (score 7):

This is the code straight out of `.Net 4.0` `Stream.CopyTo` method (bufferSize is 4096):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int count;
while ((count = this.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    destination.Write(buffer, 0, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you constructing a memory stream with an array and then trying to pull the array back out of the memory stream?

You could just do `Compress.Write(data_toCompress, 0, data_toCompress.Length);`

If you need to replace the functionality of `CopyTo`, you can create a buffer array of some length, read data from the source stream and write that data to the destination stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
infile.WriteTo(Compress);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the line:

```
Compress.Write(inFile.GetBuffer(), (int)inFile.Position, (int)(inFile.Length - inFile.Position));
```

with:

```
Compress.Write(data_toCompress, 0, data_toCompress.Length);
```

you can get rid of this line completely:

```
using (MemoryStream inFile = new MemoryStream(data_toCompress))
```

**Edit:** find an example here: [Why does gzip/deflate compressing a small file result in many trailing zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471166/why-does-gzip-deflate-compressing-a-small-file-result-in-many-trailing-zeroes)

Answer (score 0):

You should manually read and write between these 2 streams:

```
    private static void CopyStream(Stream from, Stream to)
    {
        int bufSize = 1024, count;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
        count = from.Read(buffer, 0, bufSize);
        while (count > 0)
        {
            to.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            count = from.Read(buffer, 0, bufSize);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The open-source NuGet package Stream.CopyTo implements `Stream.CopyTo` for all versions of the .NET Framework.

[Available on GitHub](https://github.com/neosmart/Stream.CopyTo) and [via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stream.CopyTo/) (`Install-Package Stream.CopyTo`)