# Save and load multiple memory streams in one file C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, memorystream

I've got two memory streams that each contain serialized structures.

Is it possible to combine these two streams into one file, in a way that can later be read and extracted back into the original two memory streams?

EDIT: I should specify that the reason my data is split into two streams at all is because the objects they contain need to be deserialized at different times. Thanks!

EDIT 2: Unfortunately, I'm using .Net 2.0. I can't take advantage of Stream.CopyTo :(

Comment: Do you have a way to identify the point where the streams diverge?  A structure count, perhaps?

Comment: When I construct the streams, I know the number and type of objects being serialized, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure many involved techniques will be suggested. I'm not a fan of complicated serialization formats.

If performance is not a big issue, consider just serializing two byte arrays. Like that:

```
class MyFileContents {
 public byte[] Part0;
 public byte[] Part1;
}

new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(myStream, new MyFileContents(...));
```

Quick to implement. Little can go wrong.

Also consider protocol buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Here I wrote you a little code snippet:

```
    public void CombineStreams(Stream src1, Stream src2, Stream dstStream)
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(dstStream))
        {
            writer.Write((int) src1.Length);
            src1.CopyTo(dstStream);
            writer.Write((int) src2.Length);
            src2.CopyTo(dstStream);
        }
    }

    public void ReadCombinedStreams(Stream srcStream, out Stream outStream1, out Stream outStream2)
    {
        outStream1 = ReadInnerStream(srcStream);
        outStream2 = ReadInnerStream(srcStream);
    }

    private Stream ReadInnerStream(Stream stream)
    {
        int length;
        byte[] content;
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            length = reader.ReadInt32();
            content = reader.ReadBytes(length);
        }

        var result = new MemoryStream(length);
        result.Write(content, 0, length);
        result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Unfortunately, I'm using .Net 2.0, and can't take advantage of Stream.CopyTo. Can you recommend an alternative, or should I write my own?

Comment: You can write your own CopyTo() extension method. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7423720) is the implementation.